# VBA-Excel text to number format issue - overwrites with wrong values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which converts text strings in a selection of cells to values. It works good, until there are some hidden rows in the Selection. Then the values beneath the hidden rows are overwritten with value from the above cell.

Do you have any ideas how to fix the code below?

```
Sub text_to_values()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

End Sub
```

Comment: why are you using `.value  = .value` , it's useless. Remove that line and the code should work fine

Comment: And again if in the end you are changing the format to `0` why to change it in the code to `General` ??\

Comment: You need to loop over the cells one-by-one (or at least loop over the `Areas` in the visible cell range): you cannot use .Value like that except on a single cell or a single-area range.  If you try it on a non-contiguous range you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @TimWilliams I was thinking about that worrying it will be slow but it seems to work pretty fast. Even for large range. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this...

```
For each cll in Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    cll.NumberFormat = “General”
    cll.Value = cll.Value
Next cll
```